# Delphi - Adding BCC & CC Recipients to OLE Outlook object

Tags: delphi, outlook, ole

The answer to the post " 
[How is working with Outlook in Delphi different than other email clients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829915/how-is-working-with-outlook-in-delphi-different-than-other-email-clients) works great. See below.

Using this example how would you go about adding CC and BCC recipients?

```
USES OleCtrls, ComObj;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  olMailItem = 0;
var
  Outlook: OLEVariant;
  MailItem: Variant;
  MailInspector : Variant;
  stringlist : TStringList;
begin
  try
   Outlook:=GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application') ;
  except
   Outlook:=CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application') ;
  end;
  try
    Stringlist := TStringList.Create;
    MailItem := Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem) ;
    MailItem.Subject := 'subject here';
    MailItem.Recipients.Add('someone@yahoo.com');
    MailItem.Attachments.Add('c:\boot.ini');
    Stringlist := TStringList.Create;
    StringList.Add('body here');
    MailItem.Body := StringList.text;
    MailInspector := MailItem.GetInspector;
   MailInspector.display(true); //true means modal
 finally
    Outlook := Unassigned;
    StringList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff866951.aspx) method of the [`Recipients`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff866751.aspx) collection creates and returns a new [`Recipient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff867569.aspx) object. The [`Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863703(v=office.15).aspx) property of the `Recipient` class allows to set an integer representing the type of recipient. For `MailItem` recipients, it can be one of the following [OlMailRecipientType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865653.aspx) constants: `olBCC`, `olCC`, `olOriginator`, or `olTo`.  The default `Type` for a new mail recipient is `olTo`.

```
MailItem.Recipients.Add('someone@yahoo.com'); // Type=1 olTo
MailItem.Recipients.Add('joesmoe@yahoo.com').Type := 2; // olCC
MailItem.Recipients.Add('alice@yahoo.com').Type := 3; // olBCC
```

You may find the [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) article helpful.