# MailItem.Recipients.Add with type 0 in Pascal

Tags: outlook, freepascal

I tried to use code from 
[this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29948153)
but when I use in code "type", I can't compile because "type" is a keyword.

```
MailItem.Recipients.Add('send@fromthis.com').Type := 0;
```

I get this error: `Fatal: Syntax error, "identifier" expected but "TYPE" found.`

How can I use it?

Answer (score 4):

`type` is a reserved word. It can be escaped by prefixing with the `&` character. So change your code to:

```
MailItem.Recipients.Add('send@fromthis.com').&Type := 0;
```